# leaflet.js beginner map showing grey screen

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to start off with leaflet.js but I'm unable to actually draw a simple map, and instead I get a grey screen.
I have an index.html, logic.js, style.css, and a config.js file where I have my mapbox api key

I have the leaflet & css links on my html file, so I don't suspect the problem to be there.

this is my logic.js file:

```
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [45.52, -122.67],
  zoom: 13
});

//Adding a tile layer (the background image map) to our Map
//We use the addTo method to add objects to our Map

L.tilelayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: "mapbox.streets",
  accessToken: api_key
}).addTo(myMap);
```

and my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Map</title>

  <!-- Leaflet CSS & JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
  crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Our CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- The div where we will inject our map -->
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- API key -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
  <!-- JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any idea what's causing my error, I'd appreciate your help.
Also, one specific question I have is: is there a difference between an "access token" and an "api key"?

Thanks

Comment: acess_token and api_key are different names for the same thing in this case.  Did you actually provide an acess token anywhere?  If you didn't, you won't be getting any tiles back because there's no token.  You can check this on the 'network' tab in your developer tools, you should see a bunch of denied requests.  Are you getting the standard zoom control in the upper left, or not even that?

Comment: @SethLutske Yes, I am getting the zoom control in the upper left, but the screen is still grey. I did provide an access token in my config.js file, which is referenced in my html file

Comment: I got it to work by changing the tilelayer part of the javascript code, but I don't know why the one I had earlier wasn't working. Also, it puts the starting point in the middle of the arctic ocean whereas the coordinates are supposed to be in Portland, which is a bit weird

Comment: What did you change?  Also make sure your lat and lng are not mixed up

Comment: I changed tileLayer to `L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "© <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/'>Mapbox</a> © <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a></strong>",
  tileSize: 512,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
  accessToken: api_key
}).addTo(myMap);`
Not sure which part of it was creating the bug, it now works, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try defining height and width to the map division. It worked for me.

```
#map{
height:100%;
width:100%
}
```